# can we use threads to bind grids in asp?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, gridview

I have a page with 10+ grids in one webform & hence it takes too much of time load the page. I went through some samples of paramterized threads to bind the grid using threads.  After modifying the code to use threads, I saw that some of the grids pre-defined events were not working.   Is there any other better way to bind such a huge amount of data, without AJAX ?

Comment: No you cannot bind in threads.

Comment: I did use paramterized threads in that page to experiment. but the implementation behaves abnormally.. sometimes everything is fine.. sometimes few of the grids does not bind data & the system throws exception saying the 'column' not found in datarow while binding the grid.. Any better solution...?

Comment: AJAX really is your friend for this kind of thing, that's what I'd recommend. If you're set on building a page like that server-side then I'd maybe look into using async data access methods and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll give a try with async data access method. It might help or not to fix the issues i'm facing, however it gives me some good knowledge.. :)

   and strange thing is the approach of using threads looks fine in staging sever but not in production

Comment: Threads are useful for CPU-intensive operations. Page loading is an IO-intensive operation with very little CPU usage. Multiple threads will not help.